# CSS is not selecting

Tags: css

I have a button in my site that is picking up this CSS from file A.

So this button:

```
<form class="recurly subscribe">
...
<button type="submit" class="submit">Subscribe</button>
```

Is styled by this CSS:

```
.recurly button.submit {
height: 46px;
```

Now I am trying to get the same CSS to style a different HTML element. I have the HTML linked to the css from file A. Here is the HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="submit recurly">Subscribe</button>
```

The HTML is a button of class submit. It is also of the class recurly. So I would expect `.recurly button.submit {...` to pick it up. The CSS file is linked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is the descendant selector, so `.recurly` is trying to select a descendant.  Elements are not descendants of themselves.

You can update the selector:

```
.recurly button.submit, button.recurly.submit
```

This will affect a `button.submit` that is a descendant of a `.recurly`, but also if the button is itself `.recurly`.  This does seem a little redundant, so you may want to just stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply use the following:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5BL3Z/)

```
.recurly button.submit.recurly {
    height: 46px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your current CSS is setup is to target the `button` element that has the class `submit` *and* is the *child* of an element with the class `recurly`. If you wish to target the button that has both `submit` and `recurly` as its class, then use:

```
button.submit.recurly {
    ...
}
```

Or use a comma to separate targets and change your original CSS from:

```
.recurly button.submit {
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
.recurly button.submit, button.submit.recurly {
    ...
}
```

This will apply whatever styles you define to both buttons.